# LNK2005 - already defined object

Tags: c++

I have two .cpp file and one .h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace characters
{
    using namespace std;
    class character{
    public:
        void info_character();
    //...
    };
}
```

I add this header file to my .cpp files. So when I want to use:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    character test();
    test.info_character();
}
```

It cause error:

> Error 1   error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall
>   characters::character::info_character(void)"
>   (?info_character@character@characters@@QAEXXZ) already defined in
>   Mechanics.obj

How to fix it (I would like to add header file to all my .cpp files)?

Comment: Is the header quoted above complete (it seems to lack, at least, include guards)? The error message looks as if `characters::character::info_character()` is defined in the header. ... or you are accidentally including the .cpp file. Another possibility is that the dependencies for Mechanics.obj were not tracked correctly and it is a left-over from an earlier version (try cleaning the project and rebuilding).

Comment: Are you sure you aren't including the header twice from anything? It does not seem to have include guards, and really ought to.

Comment: You cannot possibly be getting this error from the code you've posted. That's a linker error, and since your code cannot compile due to [vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), it cannot possibly reach linking stage.

Comment: I don't know why this is marked for close due to incomplete example code. It's obvious that the OP hasn't seen the problem but the symptoms are sufficient to get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the include file does not contain the implementation of `character::info_character` except when you use an inline implementation (what your excerpt doesn't have).

Move this code

```
void character::info_character()
{
   ...
}
```

to one of the .cpp files.